# Portable Class Library Projects Dont Work with NuGet

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, xamarin, nuget

I have a funny error where NuGet will not work in Portable Class Library projects. I have created a portable class library project and when I attempt to search (through the NuGet dialog) or install (through the console) I get the following error:

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: supportedFrameworks

[image]

I had this error with all projects (Class, etc.) in VS2012 but I followed [this](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/07/30/upgrading-nuget-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it.aspx/) advice and it has fixed it except for PCL projects. In a class project the NuGet dialog will list packages and install them just not in PCLs.

What is wrong and how can I fix this?

Note: I am creating a Xamarin Cross Platform project in VS2012 (ie the project is a PCL solution). Maybe this is the cause error - Xamarin's VS Extensions? I am also using VS2012 Professional Trial version - could this be the issue?

**Edit** Maybe I dont have my PCL setup? For example I dont have the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know Visual Studio 2012 does not include any Portable Class Libraries. They are installed with Visual Studio 2013. Otherwise you will have to install them yourself which [involves several steps](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/).

1. Install the [Portable Library Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/) and the [Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727).
2. Extract the PCLs from the .zip file that the Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6 installs into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6`.
3. Copy the PCLs extracted into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable`.
4. Repair the Xamarin install so it adds its PCL profile xml files to the new PCL directories.